# Slicing a list that is an object attribute returns " TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, list, slice

I have a question about slicing an instance attribute in a class function.

I am simulating a coffeebar  for a 5 year time period, where customers are one Time customers. Before simulating, I created a list of 1 One Time customer from the Customer class, with corresponding budget and all.

In the simulation, when a new OT customer comes in the coffee bar, I would like him to be a duplicate of the last OT customer that came in the coffee bar, and then change his class attributes with new values. But when I try to do so by slicing the OT_Customer_List to take the last element, Python returns :`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

How can i fix this?

Thanks in advance

```
OT_R_Customer_List1 = [Customer(102, budget3, order_history, amount_spent)]

class CoffeeBar(object):
    def __init__(self,[...], OT_Customer_List, [...]):
        [...]
        self.OT_Customer_List = OT_Customer_List


    def order_ts(self):
        for date in self.date_list:
            if int(random.uniform(0, 100)) >= 20:  # i.e. we get a OT customer
                  customer = self.OT_Customer_List[-1]
```

I tried to change the type of `OT_Customer_List` as `list(OT_Customer_Lit)` but nothing changed.

Comment: Check that `OT_Customer_List` is not erased or given a `None` value somewhere else in your code. If you are doing a `self.OT_Customer_List.append(last_customer)`, it's possible `last_customer` has an error and is not an instance of `Customer`, but is `None`.

Comment: `self.OT_Customer_List` is None in the last line. Make sure OT_Customer_List contains some element.